How to fusion two partitions?
When I was installing Ubuntu I read on some blog that the recommended space for swap was double that of ram memory. Since I have 16 GB, I reserved 32 GB for that partition but I realized that is too much and I resized the partition to 4 GB, so now there is 28 GB of free space and I would like to assign it to /home. How can I do it?
Here is an image of how it looks like:


I don't see any unallocated (free) space in your screenshot.

@mook765 what i want is to add those 28GB to the /home. I can use those 28GB as a disk, but i prefer to have only one partition.

Please edit your question accordingly instead of providing this relevant information in a comment. Also we can't know which of these partitions your home partition is, please clarify. As ar as I understand you'll have to remove Partition 6, resize the extended Partition 2, move Partition 3 to the left and then resize Partition 4 which I guess is your home partition. You can't edit partitions in use, so you have to boot your installer and do it from the live session.

Does this answer your question? How to resize partitions?

Firstly check what you're actually running, as whilst you do state Ubuntu, you aren't specific as to what Ubuntu product, and thus what swap you're using isn't clear. It reads to me as if you're using swap partition, but the standard swap used by modern releases is swapfile which can be very easily adjusted without needing any difficult partitioning changes.  If it's partition changes you need to make, don't forget to backup any important data, as its a dangerous process (should power be lost etc) that can cause loss to any data on disk (including partitions ignored)

Current recommendation for swap partition is 4.1GB for any system with lots of RAM. Default install uses even a smaller swap file. The old 2x of RAM was from long time ago when RAM was 1GB or less. Hibernation not recommended and then Swap needs to be just larger than RAM.

The simplest and least dangerous thing is to format that partition, after unmounting it if it was mounted, with an ext4 file system and mounting it as another folder in your /home/user/
